# Hide component on specific pages on community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

Is there a way to hide a component on specific pages? I am talking specifically using the Napil Spring '17.

I am familiar on how to create components and that I can hide them with JS but I was wondering if there was a way to do it on the server side so that the data is not rendered on the page at all.

Comment: Hi helmut, you can use page variations to display components based on user profiles. What is your criteria for "hiding components" ?

Comment: Currently it is a navigating system, I want to show it on subpages but not on the home page. So it will be on a shared location but hidden on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can try this if you are using App builder for both pages with same
>   component

In your **component** open -> **DESIGN** tab in left sidebar **Bundle Version Settings**

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="isHomePage" label="Home Page" description="Home page or not" />
</design:component>
```

> Access it as Boolean value in main component

Eg.

```
<aura:attribute name="isHomePage" type="Boolean" />
```

> In App builder there you can check or unchecked according to your page
>   type
>
> Based on Boolean value you can hide/show your data using
>   **Aura:if**

Comment: Perfect, that is def what I was looking for.